# Use Javascript array to populate Command array/list on submit?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

We're using Spring 3 MVC on the backend.

We have a page that uses the google maps api to create an array of points on the map. This array is a Javascript array (of google api Marker objects but we can just get the LatLng and then the actual long and lat values from them at any point). This is actually beside the point, the focus is on a javascript array.

The page also has a form with various other form elements (name, description for the points etc etc).

We have a form backing Command object that obviously has variables for the name, description etc and we can also add an array/list for the points, or two arrays or lists if its easier to hold the lat and longs separate and match them up later by their indexes.

We want to use javascript to actually submit the form, but before it actually submits we'd like to get that javascript array (or rather its values) into the Command object.

How can we do this?

We've seen various similar-but-not-quite questions that suggest using JSON.stringify(pointsArray) but this doesn't seem quite what we want here I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are submitting a form with javascript and you have all coords in javascript then before submitting the form just set the input field value (property of the command object) in whatever format you want. let's say you've chosen this format: `<input name="command.coords" value="[{lat:5, long:6}, {lat:7, long:8}]"` Then on the server side (for spring) you register a custom PropertyEditor (Converter) to convert your input format to the format you want on the server side (probably you'll be converting json to List)

It's similar to the CustomDateEditor used in Spring. In UI you might have different formats of the date but you register DateEditor to tell spring how to convert UI (String) format to java (Date object) format.